# How to get date from dateTime object

Tags: php, datetime, compare, diff

I'm trying to compare two dates - to check what is difference between them in minutes.
My code is:

```html
$first_date = new DateTime($token->created_at);
$first_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$second_date = new DateTime();
$second_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$difference = $first_date->diff($second_date);
$time_diff = $difference->format("%i");

var_dump($first_date);

//I get this object
object(DateTime)#552 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-04-21 10:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

How to get date from this DateTime object, so I should compare two dates and check difference betwen them.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$difference_in_hours = (($second_date->getTimestamp() - $first_date->getTimestamp())/3600);
```

if the difference between the two dates is greater than 60 minutes:

```
if($difference_in_hours>1)
{
  //if so, insert your desired code here
}
```

Comment: If difference between the two dates is for example - 2 days 0 hours 5 minutes -> will be this code working and will be ```$difference_in_hours>1``` as it should ?

Comment: @mistery_girl correct. `$difference_in_hours` literally has the amount of hours passed total. If you had 2days between them, then $difference_in_hours would be equal to 48 (meaning 48 hours).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. :)))

Answer (score 1):

Difference in seconds:

```
$diff_in_seconds = $first_date->getTimestamp() - $second_date->getTimestamp();
```

Check if diff is more than 60 minutes:

```
if($diff_in_seconds > 60 * 60){
     echo("more than 60 minutes difference");
}
```

Comment: I want to check if difference between the two dates is greater than 60 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $first_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the elapsed time in minutes as follows:

```
$interval = $first_date->diff($second_date);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%i minutes');
echo $elapsed;
```

Comment: Thank you all! I did it in this way: ```$time_diff = $difference->format("%h");``` - I should compare hours not minutes.